# How to Install Owl Carousel on Blogspot/Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger, owl-carousel

I am a newbie-ish to coding. I need to install the Owl Carousel 2 on Blogspot. It's normally designed to be installed on a Wordpress or other site where you can host folders and scripts.

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

How can I install this on a Blogger blog? I have seen it done before but can't find a tutorial to save my life.

Comment: I updated my answer I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the links to the Javascript and CSS files you need *(if you want/need Images and style also)* and place then in the `head` Portion of your Theme.
details what you need can be found in the FAQ of owl.carousel.js (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html).

Here some information form google how to change the theme (https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1227173?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969)

***Disclaimer:*** for the example I used the first CDN- Provider, that the google search returned.

You should select the Version you need(I include jQuery, just in case your theme doesn't include it):

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

I created a short Blogpost covering the answer in a bit more detail, I hope this helps https://leesflamelayout.blogspot.co.at/2017/08/how-add-custom-javascript-libraries.html